# Updating joined rows in two tables from an INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I currently have the following MySQL query, which I would like to include in a trigger, rather than as a separate query. The query updates data in two tables which are joinable:

```
UPDATE `testing_names` INNER JOIN `purchase_names`
  ON `testing_names`.`fulldomain` = `purchase_names`.`fulldomain`
SET
  `testing_names`.`account_id` = `purchase_names`.`account_id`,
  `purchase_names`.`purchase_status` = 1
WHERE `purchase_names`.`purchase_status` = 0
```

A row is (separately) inserted into `testing_names`. This row SHOULD have a corresponding entry in `purchase_names`. After a row is inserted into `testing_names`, when my UPDATE query is next run, it will update `testing_names.account_id` and update `purchase_names.purchase_status` to effectively mark this task as completed.

It makes sense to run this as part of a trigger, but I haven't been able to create a trigger that does the job.

So far, I have successfully created a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger` AFTER INSERT
    ON testing_names 
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE `testing_names` INNER JOIN `purchase_names`
          ON `testing_names`.`fulldomain` = `purchase_names`.`fulldomain`
        SET
          `testing_names`.`account_id` = `purchase_names`.`account_id`,
          `purchase_names`.`purchase_status` = 1
        WHERE `purchase_names`.`purchase_status` = 0;
      END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but evidently running a new UPDATE query is not allowed, because upon inserting a row, I get an error: `#1442 - Can't update table 'testing_names' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a trigger on a table cannot update the same table.

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Instead, you might be able to complete your update by having the trigger on testing_names update purchase_names and have another trigger on purchase_names update testing_names.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem possible to do it with mutual updating triggers, either. I am currently looking into how I could use the `testing_names` BEFORE INSERT trigger to adjust `testing_names`, then use the AFTER INSERT to adjust `purchase_names`. That should negate any need for the `purchase_names` AFTER UPDATE trigger which I believe is now causing the error.

Comment: As further information, I was able to do everything as part of the BEFORE INSERT trigger on `testing_names`, by running SELECT and UPDATE statements on the `purchase_names` table, inside a BEGIN...END.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using a Before INsert Instead